# Publish Infopath form takes very long

Tags: infopath

I am publishing a browser enabled Infopath form to Sharepoint server 2007. Once i publish the form using the publishing wizard i upload it using the Sharepoint Administratior. The upload takes 15-20mins. I found that within the Feature folder in the 12 hive the upload process re-creates all previous versions of the solution folder. Is there a way i can limit the previous versions. I tried deleting them from c:\windows\temp folder but all the previous versions re-appear upon uploading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the published .xsn file from Sharepoint Administrator and re-deploying a fresh copy resolved the issue.